# SQL - Identify unique person in a customer table with several customer ids, phone numbers and email

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, unique

I have a customer table with a unique customers id, a customer phone number and a customer email. It could happen, that a unique person can have several customer id's, but the same email and/or the same phone number. Just like this:

```
| customer id  | customer email  | customer phone number  | person id  |
|:-------------|:----------------|:-----------------------|:-----------|
| 1            |sarah@hello.com  | 0111 111111            | 1          |
| 2            |sarah@hello.com  | 0999 999999            | 1          |
| 3            |josh@world.com   | 0111 111111            | 1          | 
| 4            |josh@world.com   | 0555 555555            | 1          |
| 5            |bruno@shop.com   | 0555 555555            | 1          |
| 6            |andy@welcome.com | 0333 333333            | 6          |
| 7            |alex@welcome.com | 0333 333333            | 6          |
```

I would like to check with a SQL query in Snowflake, are there any mathes between email and phone number and create a new unique person id (e.g. customer ids 1 to 5 seem to be the same unique person because of the email and phone number and the customer id 6 and 7 are one unique person, because the phone numbers are the same). The smallest customer id of this unique person should always be taken as the person id.

How can I identify this way unique persons with a SQL query?

Thank you so much for your help & best
Sophie

Comment: It looks like you want the min (customer_id) for a lookup of a phone_number or email_id.  This is a relatively simple self-join.

Comment: @SadlyFullStack: Yes, that‘s correct.

Comment: @JimDemitriou: Oh you could be right. What would the query have to look like for a self join?

Comment: There's 2 passes you need to make, give me a min to write one up

Comment: Why would you conclude the first 5 rows are the same human being rather than 3 different people sharing a couple of phone numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit ugly, and may be improved with a window function or recursive CTE, but this is quick and dirty and generates the results you posted.  It requires two passes over the data because your result set shows a transitive relationship on the data.

```
-- Test table
    insert into
        customer (id, email, phone, person_id)
    values
        (1, 'sarah@hello.com', '0111 111111', null),(2, 'sarah@hello.com', '0999 999999', null),
        (3, 'josh@world.com', '0111 111111', null),(4, 'josh@world.com', '0555 555555', null),
        (5, 'bruno@shop.com', '0555 555555', null),(6, 'andy@welcome.com', '0333 333333', null),(7, 'alex@welcome.com', '0333 333333', null);
 
-- CTE to reflect anchor query and 2 passes to produce the results
   
    with cte as (select
        A.id,
        A.email,
        A.phone,
        min(B.id) as min_id
    from
        customer A,
        customer B
    where
        (A.email = B.email)
        or (A.phone = B.phone)
    group by
        A.id,
        A.email,
        A.phone),
    t1 as (select email, case when min(id) < min(min_id) then min(id) else min(min_id) end min_id from cte
        group by email),
    t2 as (select phone, case when min(id) < min(min_id) then min(id) else min(min_id) end min_id from cte
        group by phone),
    t3 as     
        (select cte.id, cte.email, cte.phone, case when min(t1.min_id) < min(t2.min_id) then min(t1.min_id) else min(t2.min_id) end min_id
        from cte, t1, t2
        where (cte.email = t1.email) and (cte.phone = t2.phone)
        group by 1,2,3),
    t4 as (select email, case when min(id) < min(min_id) then min(id) else min(min_id) end min_id from t3
        group by email),
    t5 as (select phone, case when min(id) < min(min_id) then min(id) else min(min_id) end min_id from t3
        group by phone)
        
    select t3.id, t3.email, t3.phone, case when min(t4.min_id < t3.min_id) then min(t4.min_id) when min(t5.min_id < t3.min_id) then min(t5.min_id) else min(t3.min_id) end person_id
    from t3, t4, t5
    where (t4.email = t3.email) and (t5.phone = t3.phone)
    group by 1,2,3
        order by t3.id;

-- Results
ID  EMAIL               PHONE       PERSON_ID
1   sarah@hello.com     0111 111111 1
2   sarah@hello.com     0999 999999 1
3   josh@world.com      0111 111111 1
4   josh@world.com      0555 555555 1
5   bruno@shop.com      0555 555555 1
6   andy@welcome.com    0333 333333 6
7   alex@welcome.com    0333 333333 6
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It actually works. Only the performance is a quite bad. In "real life" you have just a few customers more than in my example, so that the first self join takes a long of time. Have you a idea how I could get it more performant/efficient?

Comment: I probably wouldn't do this as a dynamic query over the entire result set each time like it is now.  I was originally looking to add a column to the table for "Person_ID" with a default of NULL, and rewrite this as a stored procedure and perform the multiple passes updating only the rows that had a NULL person_id.  This way you're only processing the new records with each call.